# Text wrapping a dataframe column to multiple columns with differing length constraints

Tags: python, regex, word-wrap

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, the most important of which is a Headline. I need to split this headline into multiple columns (let's say 4 columns), and each of these resulting 4 columns has an individual length constraint (column1 = 10 chars, column2 = 15 chars, column3 = 15, column4 = 25). I have researched ways of using textwrap to do this, but can't determine how to apply textwrap to a dataframe. An iterative process to split the full string into its words and recompile while checking the recompiled length against the constraint could be an option as well.

Example Headline: `Act fast. Limited space available.`
Result

```
Column1: Act fast.
Column2: Limited space
Column3: available.
Column4: (blank)
```

To make this really fun, I'm a neophyte at Python - so please be gentle.

Comment: You *could* use a regular expression like [`^(.{1,10}\b)(.{1,15}\b)(.{1,15}\b)(.{0,25}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/1FjFVw/1)

Comment: Would that retain full words (nothing hyphenated from one line to the next) for each column? I believe that is trickiest part of this. Also, could you provide the full regex line? I've never used regex before in Python. Thank you.

Comment: The regex expression worked beautifully! I even used the index of the resulting list to identify the first column - a minor miracle for me right now. The last question (hopefully) is how do I apply the regex to a column in the dataframe instead a simple text string? Thank you for the quick original answer!

Answer (score 1):

See the whole solution here:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'junk': 'Act fast. Limited space available.'}
df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), columns=['raw_text'])

df = df['raw_text'].str.extract(r'^(?P<column1>.{1,10}\b)(?P<column2>.{1,15}\b)(?P<column3>.{1,15}\b)(?P<column4>.{0,25}\b)', expand=True)
print(df)
```

This yields

```
      column1         column2    column3 column4
0  Act fast.   Limited space   available
```